# Is it possible to test whether an interface inheits another interface using reflection?

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, interface

So I have the following `Interface`:

```
public interface Interface2 : Interface1
{
   //Properties here
}
```

and a `Class` like so:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public Interface2 MyDataAccess { get; set; }

   public void TestInheritance()
   {
        foreach (var property in typeof(MyClass).GetProperties())
        {
            var type = property.PropertyType;
            var inheritsproperty = type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Interface1));
            if (type is Interface1 || inheritsproperty)
            {
                //never hit
            }
        }
   }
}
```

and looking at it I would expect the above code to work,

But the `inheritsProperty` property is always false, and `type is Interface1` is always false.

So is it possible to check if one interface inherits another using reflection? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `type is Interface1` is not how you use `is` operator. It is used to check if instance is compatible with type (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx). To compare types use `typeof` and equality operator, eg. `type == typeof(Interface1 )`.

Comment: partial true,  the comparison is true, but `type == typeof(Interface1 )` is only when the type == interface1

Comment: Correct. To also check the inheritance tree, one should use `IsAssignableFrom()` instead.

Comment: You only need to check the `IsAssignableFrom()` because: `typeof(Interface1).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Interface1)) == true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should swap the types: *(tested)*

```
var inheritsproperty = type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Interface1));
```

Should be:

```
var inheritsproperty = typeof(Interface1).IsAssignableFrom(type);
```

It's kinda vague naming, but it says, `Can you assign <parameter> to the caller/source type.`

---

Makes:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public Interface2 MyDataAccess { get; set; }

   public void TestInheritance()
   {
        foreach (var property in typeof(MyClass).GetProperties())
        {
            var type = property.PropertyType;

            var inheritsproperty = typeof(Interface1).IsAssignableFrom(type);

            if (inheritsproperty)
            {
                //does hit
            }
        }
   }
}
```